# Facebook/Webview controls on Android Tv

Tags: android, facebook, webview, android-tv

I'm trying to get Facebook login working for Android TV but none of the elements in the WebView that popups gains focus.

We're starting the Facebook login process by using the `Session.openActiveSession(getActivity, true, pCallback)` function and we are using `v3.18.1` of the Facebook SDK.

Unfortunately it's a non-trivial task to update the SDK to the latest version but I had a look through the version notes and didn't see anything related to non-touch input.

I've had a look at the output from other Android TV games which do work with the Facebook login popup and I haven't been able to determine anything from the limited output that goes to `logcat`.

Does anyone know how to give the WebView elements focus so they can be navigated with a dpad?

Answer (score 0):

Not with Facebook, but I've got it working by simulating a click on the element:

```
document.getElementById(elementId).click();
```

I tried to use .focus(), but that didn't make any difference in my case.

Update: Once the webview has the focus, D-pad navigation (with the square around the clickable items) is re-enabled. Navigation will change between links containing either text or images.